# unable to import scitools python

Tags: python, python-2.7, scitools

I have just installed scitools-0.8 and I'm trying to import it using `from scitools.std import *`

but I get an error message saying

> ImportError: No module named oldnumeric.mlab
>
> numpy import filed!
>
> see doc of scitools.numpytools module for how to choose Numeric instead.

I don't want to be using Numeric since the book I'm learning from uses numpy and I've read around and it seems that numpy doesn't support oldnumeric any more.

I don't know how to get scitools to work. I am using Python 2.7

There is a similar duplicate to this but the answer it has is basically just don't use scitools

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version of `scitools` you are using is ancient. Try cloning [this repo](https://github.com/hplgit/scitools) and running `[sudo] python setup.py install`. The version number is 0.9.0, but some bug fixes have been pushed to the repo since its release. I just did this on Ubuntu 16.04, and running `from scitools.std import *` seems to work just fine.

By the way, though, the form `from XXX import *` is generally NOT a good idea, as it pollutes the local namespace and can potentially overwrite other functions. Instead, try `from scitools import std` or `import scitools.std as s` so all the functions within that module are in their own namespace.

Comment: thanks a lot that worked just fine on Python 2.7, any idea how I can make it work on python 3.5?

Comment: @user3333708 not very easily - you could start by running `2to3` on the source, but likely you'll have to do manual debugging as well. There are a bunch of sneaky differences between 2 and 3 like module name changes, different ways of handling inheritance, `xrange` vs. `range`, `map` becoming a built-in, `raw_input` and `input`, and many more. You might want to file an issue first and see if it's on the maintainer's radar. Good luck!

Comment: Check out [this issue](https://github.com/hplgit/scitools/issues/21) and the associated patch - it may help.

Comment: Get the badge soon ;)