# Python How to install Scitool Understand

Tags: python, import

I am trying to install "understand" from Scitool in python. I do not know if I miss anything, but if I do

```
pip install understand
```

It always install another library "understand" not from the scitool.

Thank you very much

Comment: Does this answer your question? [unable to import scitools python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38172774/unable-to-import-scitools-python)

Comment: Actually no, I found that post initially, after I install the scitools, and import scitools and understand, still not work, actually from this manual "https://documentation.scitools.com/html/python/understand.html", they just simply import understand, but I could not

Comment: You should probably ask at "Super User" instead.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to run `pip install understand` because this understand library is not the 'scitools understand' library. The first step you should take is find upython.exe in the same directory as understand.exe, then run the upython.exe in your terminal. You should be able to run `import understand` and use Understand API normally in Python at that time.